# Update a columns if certain value

Tags: sql

I have a certain column in a table that stores a number. I want this number to be set to 2 ONLY if it previously equaled 1. I was wondering if it was possible to avoid this:

```php
$val = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT columnA FROM tableName WHERE something = '$someValue'"));

if($val[0] == 1) { .....UPDATE tableName SET columnA = 2....... }
```

Is it possible to directly query the database? With something like this:

```
SET columnA = 2 if columnA = 1
```

Comment: There is really no need to bring PHP logic into this, just do it all in one MySQL UPDATE statement as seen below

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually the query you're looking for should be:

```
update tableName set columnA = 2
where columnA = 1
```

The "if" you're mentioning is actually a condition. And these conditions are set in the where clause of the update statement.

That's it :)

Answer (score 3):

Why not just do an update with conditions?

```
UPDATE tableName SET columnA = '2' WHERE columnA = '1'
```

That should do what you are looking for

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE tableName SET columnA = 2 WHERE columnA = 1
```