# MySQL Update column if value equal to any value of an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a table with a column that store a number. I also have 2 different array: the first one store the value to check, the second one store the new value to save in the column.
I need a query that check if the value in the column is equal to any value of the first array and if it is true update the column value with the same position value of the second array.
For example:

```
column value = 2
firstArray = [1, 2, 3]
secondArray = [5, 6, 7]
```

I want to check if 2 is in firstArray: yes... it is equal to firstArray[1]
then I want to update the column value with secondArray[1]
at the end of the query column value will be 6.

It is possibile?
I found this [MySQL: Update a columns if certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188966/mysql-update-a-columns-if-certain-value) but I'm really new in querying MySQL and I don't know how to make it work in my case.

Thanks for the help
Daniele

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: the database is huge (almost than 4 million records) so I think the best way is to run an SQL query in phpmyadmin. If it is not possibile I usually use php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
$combined=array_combine( $1array, $2array);
```

First array is with keys the second with values.[**Docs**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

```
foreach ($combined as $key => $val) {
  if($key=2){
  $query = "UPDATE table SET Column= '$val' WHERE Column = '$key'";
  mysqli_query($query);
 }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. I'm going to try it. There's a way to do this with a SQL query from phpmyadmin?

Comment: @danipen I doubt it,but I`m no SQL expert.I`ll think about it.

Comment: It takes a while (alf an hour) to update all the table (+4000000 records) but it works fine! thanks

Comment: @danipen may be you need to index you Column field