# how to update multiple rows with same value in mysql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

Hi I have a table data as below

[image: Now i want to update Department column data of "DA" to "DATA ANALYTICS". How can i write single update query to update the data?]

Comment: I want to update all department column data consisting "DA" to "DATA ANALYTICS" in a single query. Help me with this

Comment: What have you tried that does not work ?

Comment: That's a very simple update with a where - what have you got so far?

Comment: i have to write 7 update queries to update.for example - update emp set 'department'='DATA ANALYTICS' where pk_id = 1; so on. But is it possible to do with single query

Comment: 'i have to write 7 update queries' - errm no..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update a columns if certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188966/update-a-columns-if-certain-value)

Comment: Why does your title say "MySQL", but your tag is [tag:sql-server]? You need to learn what RDBMS you are *really* using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this , Thanks

```
UPDATE emp SET department='DATA ANALYTICS' WHERE department='DA'
GO
```

Comment: Go is a sqlserver thing , mysql statement should be semi colon (;) terminated and this is a copy of a previous answer.

Comment: `GO` is not T-SQL no, but it *is* SQL Server related, @Squirrel . No one said it *was* T-SQL.

Answer (score 1):

The statement would look like this

```
UPDATE your_table_name
SET Department= 'DATA ANALYTICS'
WHERE Department='DA';
```